# How to make an invisible character in HTML, that still get's picked up on text selection?

Tags: html, css, character, spreadsheet

#### Backstory

So I am doing a webchat as a side-project, and one of the issues I am encountering is making the UX of copying and pasting messages friendly.

Right now all of the elements are organized within their own tags, spaced out and separated with CSS rules, in a way that if you try copying a part of the chat log, it comes out as `23:49userHello World`.

The solution I have thought of is to have a zero-width tab character separating them, that still gets picked up by text selection, and when pasted as raw text is just a normal tab. This would not only separate it in copy paste actions, but it would make it super easy to parse using `awk`.

#### TL;DR

How would I modify a printable tab character (`&#09;`) with CSS, or any character by that matter, in a way that it's invisible to the layout, but still gets picked up in text selections?

Comment: Exclusively using CSS? Also, I guess you'd be looking for a cross-browser solution, right?

Comment: Preferrably, yeah. Also cross-browser is highly desireable, although I wouldn't bother with IE. But feel free to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Funny thing, there's at least a CSS-only solution that works on IE but not on the others :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all of the elements are organized within their own tags, you could use `:after` with the character that you want as separator in the content (with `font-size:0`). As far as I know, this solution will only work on IE, as the other browsers don't select the pseudo-elements):

```
span:after {
    content: " ";
    font-size:0;
}
```

You can see it on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc7jrdff/1/ (Remember only on IE!)

Another CSS possibility would be to add the special character directly when you generate the page, and apply the `::first-letter` pseudo-element. The problem of this solution is that not all characters will count as a first letter (blank space doesn't)

Using JavaScript, you could come up with a solution that works in all the browsers: append your character to the elements (again with `font-size:0`):

```
// CSS
span.hiddenChar {
    font-size:0;
}

// JS
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span").prepend("<span class='hiddenChar'> </span>");
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/bc7jrdff/2/

Or if you prefer JavaScript without jQuery:

```
// HTML
<span class="data">23:49</span><span class="data">user</span><span class="data">Hello World!</span>

// JS
var aux = document.querySelectorAll(".data");
for (x = 0; x < aux.length; x++) {
    aux[x].innerHTML = "<span class='hiddenChar'> </span>" + aux[x].innerHTML;
};
```

You can see that on this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc7jrdff/4/

Comment: I'm gonna hang on this for a while, try to figure something out. I didn't even have plans for supporting IE, and the reason copy paste doesn't have separators is because I'm using `:after` and `:before` in the first place lol.
Also the idea of loading jQuery just for this terrifies me.

Comment: On this line, maybe you could use `::first-letter` (again with the `font-size:0` and just place the character you want when generating the page, no JavaScript)

Comment: Thats what I'm running experiments with at the moment. Modifying the font with a specially crafted `TAB` character is also an option, but since I'm loading from Google Fonts, thats rather impossible. Feel free to add it to your answer, also please consider putting a no-jQuery JS answer in there alongside the jQuery one. I'll mark your answer as correct for completeness then.

Comment: I'll add it to the answer, but don't mark it as solution unless it solves the problem.

Comment: I have also added a pure JavaScript solution without using jQuery

Comment: I'm still doing some tests, probably gonna sleep on this. Anyhow thanks for the great answer! I'm testing all options, if I get a fix I'll mark your answer.

Comment: Bear in mind that, for IE compatibility, you'd have more support using `document.querySelectorAll('.aux')` (for IE8 and up), instead of `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas, I updated the response with your suggestion.